# zbar library for android Does it scan Interleaved 2 of 5 barcode?

Tags: android, zbar

I have integrated the zbar library to scan barcodes.
Apart from Interleaved 2 of 5 barcode, it scans all others barcodes which is written in document.

So I am curious whether zbar supports Interleaved 2 of 5 or not?
Beacuse this format is also supported in document.
But I am not able to scan Interleaved 2 of 5 barcode.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could use the ZXING library. It does support ITF. They have  App named Barcode Scanner so you can try it.

Answer (score 1):

> public static final int I25 = 25;

Taken from net.sourceforge.zbar.Symbol. Seems it's supported. Check how do you initialize a Scanner, maybe you have to point what formats should it supported (in my Android lib i implicitly declaring that i want only QR codes to be recognized).

Comment: By default it should take all supported format so I am not specifying any format but still its not working for I25